# Can't get XRDP running on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop, xrdp

As the title suggests, I am trying to get XRDP running on a new Jammy install but am getting this:

```
dave@Python:~$ sudo systemctl status xrdp
× xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-03-14 18:23:49 CST; 13h ago
       Docs: man:xrdp(8)
             man:xrdp.ini(5)
        CPU: 16ms

mar 14 18:23:49 Python xrdp[4508]: [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 4
mar 14 18:23:49 Python xrdp[4508]: [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
mar 14 18:23:49 Python xrdp[4508]: [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
mar 14 18:23:49 Python xrdp[4508]: [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
mar 14 18:23:49 Python xrdp[4508]: [ERROR] g_tcp_bind(8, 3389) failed bind IPv6 (errno=98) and IPv4 (errno=22).
mar 14 18:23:49 Python xrdp[4508]: [ERROR] trans_listen_address failed
mar 14 18:23:49 Python xrdp[4508]: [ERROR] Failed to start xrdp daemon, possibly address already in use.
mar 14 18:23:49 Python systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
mar 14 18:23:49 Python systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mar 14 18:23:49 Python systemd[1]: Failed to start xrdp daemon.
```

`netstat -an | grep "LISTEN " | grep ":3389"` returns no entries

`sudo ufw status` returns `Status: inactive`

`sudo netstat -tlpn | grep 3389` returns no entries

Settings -> Sharing is off.  (Not using sharing even tho I am connecting from a Windows box because I need to run this box headless.)

Comment: I had the same issue. Couldn't solve it. However I'm using Thincast RDP client. Works very well.

Comment: @ArjunKShibu What are you using for the RDP server?

Comment: I used RDP to connect to my Windows AWS Instance. I used Remmina and GNOME connections, but the clipboard didn't work. At last found the mentioned software.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using Griffon's XRDP script from here:
http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=18725

I ran it first with the -r (remove) flag to get rid of all the stuff I tried that hadn't worked and then ran it again with no flags for a default installation and I was able to connect with the Windows RDP app first try.

Brilliant!